# Dynamics CRM How to present external data when viewing an account

Tags: integration, crm, microsoft-dynamics

When my users view an account, they also want to see data from another system, which is retrieved from a web service on demand (i.e. not stored or cached in CRM). Can Dynamics' web customisation, or other integration features, support this, given XSS restrictions? 
The platform is Dynamics Online 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML WebResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx), just like any other html page, use JavaScript to retrieve and display your records.

Customize the account form and embed the created html on to the form.

[image: customization]

Comment: This is prevented by XSS restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Along with a HTML web resource, you could also consider the following:

- Silverlight web resource (though that is somewhat out of vogue these days).
- IFrame another website with your custom content.
- Use a ribbon/command bar button to open a website in a popup window which displays the custom content.

Edit:

---

If you used a HTML web resource I don't think XSS restriction would be a problem. Say for example, you use a HTML web resource, you can then query and present data from the other applications web service. I dont think XSS comes into play here as the HTML web resource is all contained within CRM.

For either an IFrame or HTML web resource you can configure CRM to pass [contextual information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328034.aspx#BKMK_PassFormData).

> You can provide contextual information by passing parameters to the
>   URL defined in the control. The page that is displayed in the frame
>   must be able to process parameters passed to it. All the parameters in
>   the following table [including record Id] are passed if the IFRAME or web resource is
>   configured by using the Pass record object-type code and unique
>   identifier as parameters option.

You can configure XSS restrictions per [IFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328034.aspx#BKMK_IframeSecurity).

> Use the Restrict cross-frame scripting, where supported option when
>   you don’t fully trust the content displayed in an IFRAME.

So I think all of these options will work in various configurations.

Comment: •Silverlight thx, but n.thx :-)


•IFrame - this is prevented by XSS restrictions


•Cannot pass account entity as a parameter

Comment: James Thx, I have an iframe displaying external data. I haven't figured out what restrictions apply yet, but priorities have changed so I'll have to come back to this.